# Why would this generic with a mapped type accept null?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

This code example will explain it better than words :

```
class Foo<T extends {[K in keyof T]: any}> {
  foo!: T;
}

declare const group: Foo<{foo: string}>; // OK
declare const group2: Foo<null>;         // OK 

type obj = {[K in keyof null]: any}
//   ^? {}

class Bar<T extends {}> {
  bar!: T;
}
declare const group3: Bar<{bar: string}>; // OK
declare const group4: Bar<null>;          // KO
```

What is the difference between these 2 generic classes ?
Why does the first one accept `T = null` but not the 2nd one ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVaBTAHgF3QOwBMYBvAbQGloBLPaAa3QE94AzaFAXQC5ow9GAvgD5oxAFDRoLRAEIeKANxiBYsQXSgwAJ3TRg8PBGzQA5lvgBXAA48EyYtPg8jWmieFL1mnXoNHT5tYATLaISHgWICBCSmLYjFa68ABGAFbQALyiFNS0DMxsEVHcvPwqAPTlktAAegD8qppQ0ABC2qgYOPhEosKiEtDJ2nLsSipe4D76hsZmllYAzDxtWkjEQ1rO2K547jFqGpO60-5z1gAsy+1F0UpAA)

Answer (score 0):

Utility types such as mapped types don't have any intrinsic meaning.

The fact that `keyof null` produces `never` and ends up generating an object with no required properties does not make `null` assignable to every possible object.

`null` is only assignable to `null` (or `null | undefined` with `strictNullChecks: false`) by definition, so it is rejected by `T extends {}`

---

Sorry there is an important portion missing from my answer: when `T` is generic, the mapped type expression returns it unchanged if it's a base type

```js
type Mapper<T> = {[K in keyof T]: any}

Mapper<string> // string
Mapper<2> // 2
Mapper<null> // null
```

So this is why the behaviour is not the same: when you wrote `Foo<null>`, `T` constraint was `null`

Comment: Furthermore `{}` is defined as "any non-nullish value" and not as "empty object". So for Bar, null is the only forbidden input, it takes any other value as input e.g 3 or "test".

Comment: Do you might know a way of making `T` incompatible with null for `Foo<T>` while keeping the mappedtype ?  An intersection `{[K in keyof T]: any} & {}` doesn't do the trick

Comment: You want to use `object` when you need to exclude base types: `{[K in keyof T]: any} & object` would do but it is strictly equivalent to `object`.